# Jtable and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, resultset

I'm getting and error when i'm try to do the below coding. I can't understand the this netbeans error. The error is as follows.

```
Mar 21, 2013 2:28:19 AM timetable.generator.JFTTGenerator6 jButton2ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
```

Please help me !!!!

```
String subj=(String) jTable1.getValueAt(0,1 );
Connection con = Driver.connect();
ResultSet lec1=Handler.getData(con,
"select lec_id from lecdetails,subjects where subjects.sub_code=lecdetails.sub_code 
 and subjects.sub_name='"+subj+"'");
ResultSet rst1= Handler.getData(con, "select sub_name from subjects,lecdetails 
where subjects.sub_code=lecdetails.sub_code and subjects.sem='2nd' and 
lecdetails.lec_id  <> '"+lec1.getString(1) +"' order by rand() limit 1 ");
jTable2.setValueAt(lec1.getString(1), 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before using `lec.getString(1)`, you have to call `next()`.

So, before the statement
`ResultSet rst1= Handler.getData`,

add

```
if (lec1.next()){
    //second result set statement.
    //set value in jtable
}
```